# How to prevent document from creating new popup windows onclick event of user using javascript

Tags: javascript, block, popupwindow

In my wordpress site, some hacker has embedded a script into it somewhere.

The problem I'm having now is, whenever the site is opened, the first time a user clicks anywhere on it, a spam popup appears, due to the hacker's script.

Is there any way I can prevent the popup window from being created with Javascript?

If I can't prevent it, is there any way that I can close the popup using JS? Unfortunately, since the other script is creating it, I don't have a reference to the opened window. I've seen other scripts calling `.close()` on an opened window, but I don't have a reference to the new window, so I don't know how to close it.

[Here's my site.](https://vuonlinesupport.com/)

Comment: If your site is hacked, revert to a prior version. There are ways to prevent popups, but it's a *very* X/Y problem for your situation

Comment: @CertainPerformance  can you please provide any solution to prevent popup using js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup on your site is opened by something calling `window.open`. You can prevent it by assigning something else to `window.open` *and* running your script before the other script does:

```
window.open = () => undefined;
```

(This does work, if I run this code on your site before your site's Javascript runs, no windows get opened)

It's not uncommon for a client to want to implement this, but if you're the server, it'd be better to fix the server to remove the malicious code, rather than try to patch around it.

Comment: @ CertainPerformance  if i implement the code above when the document is ready will it prevent popup if user click anywhere in the doc ?

Comment: It depends on when the malicious code runs, and what it references. To be *sure* that the malicious code cannot open windows with `window.open`, monkeypatch `window.open` as soon as possible, before the malicious code runs. (If the malicious code runs first, it will be able to save references to things before you can break the reference)

Comment: @ CertainPerformance it works is there any flaw of doing this ? By the way Thanks for the quick round off.

Comment: Aside from the fact that malicious code still exists on your site - the only real issue would be that you'd be unable to use `window.open` on your own. If you want to be able to use it, assign it to a different variable before reassigning it, eg `const originalOpen = window.open; window.open = () => undefined` and then reference `originalOpen`